# Meaning of “come neither to praise nor to bury"

Tags: meaning-in-context

What is the meaning of "come to" in the mentioned sentence?

> In this paper I **come** neither **to** praise nor to bury internalism.

Answer (score 1):

It's a literary [allusion](https://literarydevices.net/allusion/) misquoting [Act III, Scene 2](http://shakespeare.mit.edu/julius_caesar/julius_caesar.3.2.html) of Shakespeare's play, *Julius Caesar*, in which Mark Antony famously says:

> Friends, Romans, countrymen, lend me your ears; 
>   I come to bury Caesar, not to praise him.